# Sinnieren korrekter Fall

Tags: grammatical-case, grammaticality

Ich stolperte kürzlich über folgenden Satz:

> Ich sinnierte über eine Idee

Ist das korrektes Deutsch? Muss es nicht heißen "über einer Idee"?

Comment: Gibt es einen Grund, an den Angaben der Wörterbücher zu zweifeln? https://www.dwds.de/wb/sinnieren https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/sinnieren

Comment: förmlich korrekt wäre "sinnen", "Er besinnt sich". Dagegen scheint mir "sinnieren" wie eine Verbalhornung.

Comment: *über* meaning "concerning" always takes the accusative. This is quite independent of the verb.

Answer (score 3):

Das Verb *sinnieren* verlangt das Objekt, über das nachgedacht wird, im Akkusativ:

> richtig: Ich sinniere über **dich.** *(Akkusativ)*
>
> falsch: Ich sinniere über **<del>du</del>.** *(Nominativ)*
>   falsch: Ich sinniere über **<del>deiner</del>.** *(Genitiv)*
>   falsch: Ich sinniere über **<del>dir</del>.** *(Dativ)*

Man kann aber auch den Ort angeben, an dem man dieses Sinnieren praktiziert. Wenn sich dieser Ort oberhalb eines bestimmten Bezugspunkts befindet, kann man ebenfalls die Präposition *über* verwenden, muss dann aber den Bezugspunkt im Dativ nennen.

> Else war auf die Spitze des höchstens Turms des Doms geklettert.
>   Sie sinnierte über der Stadt über das Leben.

Hier steht *»der Stadt«* im Dativ, weil es der Bezugspunkt der Ortsangabe ist, und *»das Leben«* steht im Akkusativ, weil es der Gegenstand des Sinnierens ist.

Nachdem Ideen keine Orte sind, kommen sie hier nur als Gegenstände des Sinnierens in Frage, müssen also im Akkusativ stehen:

> richtig: Ich sinnierte über **eine Idee.**
>   falsch: Ich sinnierte über **<del>einer Idee</del>.**

Comment: Ich gebe dir Recht, dass *sinnieren über* normalerweise mit dem Akkusativ einhergeht. Aber: An sich kann ich keine Vorschrift finden, die das genauso verlangt - Man kann sich durchaus vorstellen, dass in Sonderfällen, z.B. wenn die Gedanken grübelnd ins Stocken geraten und keine "Bewegung" mehr vorliegt, auch der Dativ angebracht sein kann.

Comment: @tofro: Zu Vorschriften (im Kontext der Benutzung von Sprachen): Die Sprecher einer Sprache scheren sich ohnehin einen Dreck um Vorschriften. Das was zählt ist wie andere Sprecher sprechen. Sprache funktioniert über Nachahmung dessen was man von anderen wahrnimmt. Wenn sich zwei Menschen, die dieselbe Muttersprache sprechen, miteinander unterhalten, wird keiner von beiden permanent das explizite amtliche Regelwerk dieser Sprache im Kopf durchgehen. Das tatsächlich benutzte "Regelwerk" liegt als implizites Wissen vor, das man sich durch Beobachtung und Gebrauch angeeignet hat. ...

Comment: ... Das explizite Regelwerk, das in Büchern steckt, ist der Versuch, dieses implizite Wissen zuerst einmal überhaupt explizit zu machen (d.h. auszuformulieren), und dann auch zu vereinheitlichen. Denn zwei verschiedene Sprecher müssen nicht unbedingt dieselben impliziten Regeln anwenden. Vor allem dann nicht, wenn sie aus unterschiedlichen Regionen oder sozialen Schichten kommen. Daher ist das, was man als Regeln niedergeschrieben findet, immer nur der Versuch, einen kleinsten gemeinsamen Nenner zu finden, und auf ewig dazu verdammt dem tatsächlichen Gebrauch hinterherzuhinken.

Comment: "Ich sinniere über dir", "ick liebe dir" funktioniert im richtigen Dialekt. Ich glaube eher, die Wörterbücher bzw die Verfasser und deren Vorbilder eilen dem Gebrauch vorraus.

Comment: @vectory: Im richtigen Dialekt funktioniert fast alles. In den hinteren Enden von Alpentälern oder auf kleinerem Ostseeinseln blühen in den Dialekten ja die wundersamsten sprachlichen Raritäten. Aber das hat in Regelwerken, die für den gesamten deutschen Sprachraum gelten sollen, nichts verloren. Man muss auch zwischen Wörterbüchern (in denen ja nur die Rechtschreibung abgebildet wird) und Grammatikbüchern (welche die Regeln der Sprache enthalten) unterscheiden. Ich habe von der Grammatik gesprochen, du offenbar von der Rechtschreibung. Die Autoren von Wörterbüchern listen nur Wörter auf, ...

Comment: ... die sie in einer Sprache gefunden haben und definieren damit deren Rechtschreibung. Sie geben zwar auch an, zu welcher Beugungsklasse sie gehören, aber sie beschreiben nicht, wie diese Wörter auf die Struktur eines sie umgebenden Satzes wirken. Das steht nämlich in einem Grammatikbuch. Man kann die Standard-Rechtschreibung einer Sprache per Verordnung diktieren, weil die Rechtschreibung nur eine Konvention zur Speicherung von Sprache ist und in der Sprache selbst gar nicht enthalten ist. Die Rechtschreibung ist zwar ein nützliches, aber eben auch ein künstlich geschaffenes Beiwerk  ...

Comment: ... einer Sprache. Man kann jede beliebige Sprache absolut perfekt sprechen, ohne auch nur die geringste Ahnung von Rechtschreibung zu haben. Es gibt ja auch viele Sprachen, die gar keine Schrift haben. Aber bei der Grammatik geht das nicht. Ohne Grammatik kann man nicht verständlich sprechen. Daher ist die Grammatik (gemeinsam mit dem Wortschatz) das was eine Sprache ausmacht. Die Wörter sind die Bausteine, und die Grammatik regelt, wie man diese Bausteine aneinanderfügen kann. Die Rechtschreibung ist nur eine Kodierung, um Sprache auf Papier (oder einem anderen Medium) zu speichern. Eine ...

Comment: ... Sprache lebt im Wortschatz und in der Grammatik, nicht aber in der Rechtschreibung. Und die Veränderungen von Wortschatz und Grammatik kann man nicht vorhersagen, dazu unterliegen sie viel zu vielen Einflüssen. Daher ist es gar nicht möglich, dass die Autoren der Grammatikbücher dem tatsächlichen Gebrauch vorauseilen. Sie sind auf ewig dazu verdammt, dem Gebrauch hinterherzuhinken.

Answer (score 0):

Der unbestimmte Artikel steht nur im Singular und hier im Akkusativ und nicht im  Dativ. `Idee` ist als Substantiv ein Femininum. Es muss daher richtig heißen:

> Ich sinnierte über eine Idee.

Vielleicht hilft eine alte Merkregel:

Über *wen* (Akkusativ) habe ich sinniert (nachgedacht)? => über **eine** Idee.

Comment: Die Frage war aber nicht, wie der Akkusativ grammatikalisch korrekt gebildet wird, sondern ob *sinnieren* den Akkusativ oder eventuell nicht doch den Dativ erfordert. Deine Antwort geht somit an der Frage vorbei.